# How to get number from docker-compose up --scale

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elixir

I am trying to create scale-able docker container running an Elixir node. Currently I have this:

```
client:
  image: elixir:alpine
  command:
    elixir --name client@somewhere.localdomain --cookie pass 
           -S mix run --no-halt -e Connect.main ${CONTROLLER}
  depends_on:
    - system_control
```

The elixir node is just using `Node.connect` to inform the controller of its existence. However, if I try creating more client nodes with `docker-compose up --scale client=5` then only the first one is able to connect and the rest are refused (presumably) because of name clashes caused by the hardcoded `--name`. Any idea how to circumvent it? Is there a way of getting some unique id to be used instead of `somewhere`?

Edit: my Connect.main elixir script is (abridged) this:

```
defmodule Connect do
  def main do
    [server] = System.argv
    IO.puts "#{Node.self} - Connecting to #{server} - #{ Node.connect(:'#{server}') }
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `container_name` from your docker-compose.yml? Docker will assign container names automatically, so this may solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It indeed gives them automatic names as `directoryName_client_1` and so on. However, elixir still cannot automatically get assigned a 'long name' and therefore the problem still persists. I will edit my question to remove container_name.

Comment: What about creating a unique id within the alpine bash (e.g. `uuidgen` if installed) and then using a name like `--name client@${uuidgen}.localdomain` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a name with a randomized component should solve your problem. Make sure it is random enough that duplicates are highly improbable. You might want to avoid sequential IDs in some cases as suggested in [this Docker-Compose issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4167)

As @fl9 suggested, using some kind of command line UUID generator like `uuidgen` might be able to do the trick.